# Update com JOIN com 2 tabelas junto com Select

Tags: sql, select, join, sql-update

Olá, estou com a seguinte *query* pra realizar em um banco de dados porém travei em uma situação, abaixo segue a *query*, a mensagem de erro e em seguida a explicação.

## Trecho do Código

```
USE BDTESTE
GO

UPDATE NotaFiscalItens SET CODIGOPRODUTO = 
(SELECT B.CODIGO FROM EstoqueMercadorias as B
WHERE 
         CAST(B.REFERENCIACLIENTE as INTEGER) = CAST(CODIGOPRODUTO as INTEGER) 
AND B.EMPRESA = 1) 
WHERE 
    EMPRESA = 22 
AND SERIE = 2 
AND OPERACAO = 133 
AND DATA BETWEEN convert(smalldatetime,'01/06/2020',103) AND convert(smalldatetime,'30/06/2020',103)
GO
```

## Erro

***Mensagem 207, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 13

Nome de coluna 'DATA' inválido.

Mensagem 207, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 13

Nome de coluna 'DATA' inválido.***

## Explicação

No segundo **WHERE** onde se lê:
`"AND DATA BETWEEN convert(smalldatetime,'01/06/2020',103) AND convert(smalldatetime,'30/06/2020',103)"`
o campo **DATA** ele vem de uma outra tabela chamada **NOTAFISCAL**, e já tentei de tudo que é jeito pesquisado na internet, encaixar um **JOIN** com essa tabela **NOTAFISCAL** nessa *query* pra que eu consiga que respeite essa condição do período inicial e final da emissão das notas para que seja atualizado o código das mercadorias das notas fiscais emitidas pois elas vem de uma integração com outro software e preciso fazer esse update que é praticamente um **DE/PARA**, com isso o saldo do estoque vai ficar correto.

***Fico grato se alguém puder me ajudar.***

Comment: Siga este exemplo em Inglês: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql-server) . o objetivo será fazer o join entre a tabela nota fiscal e nota fiscal items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem diversos modos de realizar um **UPDATE** com **INNER JOIN**, o método mais fácil e que evita erros é realizar um **SELECT** como se fosse um cruzamento de tabelas e trazer o valor **Antigo** e o **Novo** e depois dar um SET com o apelido do valor **Novo** e **Antigo**, conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
UPDATE 
     (SELECT tb1.valor_antigo AS OLD, tb2.valor_novo AS NEW
      FROM tabela_1 as tb1
      INNER JOIN tabela_2 as tb2
        ON tb1.cd_tabela = tb2.cd_tabela
      WHERE tb1.valor >= 100
      AND tb1.valor <= 200) up
SET up.OLD = up.NEW;
```

Como pode ver eu utilizei o **WHERE**, **INNER JOIN** e outros comandos do **SELECT** para depois realizar o **UPDATE**.